# Glusterfs mirrored server changes owner

Tags: linux, glusterfs

I have configured glusterfs over a master-client server which replicates to a slave server into the same route, glusterfs was installed with root user on both servers.

**** In both servers I have this users: ****

```
omar
johan
charlie
nisha
robert
```

The installation steps were this:

```
# apt-get install glusterfs-server
# gluster peer probe slave
# gluster peer status
> State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)
# gluster volume create replica replica 2 transport tcp master-client:/home/charlie/replica slave:/home/charlie/replica
# gluster volume start replica
```

Configuring client over master-client

```
# mkdir /home/charlie/replica_editor
# mount.glusterfs master-client:/replica /home/charlie/replica_editor
```

Testing cluster, creating file over replica_editor using charlie as user:

```
charlie@master-client:~/replica_editor$ touch test
root@master-client:/home/charlie/replica_editor# ls -ltr
>        -rw-rw-r-- 1 charlie   charlie  0 May 26 08:56 test
```

Seeing over main server replica file system:

```
root@master-client:/home/charlie/replica# ls -ltr
>        -rw-rw-r-- 1 charlie   charlie  0 May 26 08:56 test
```

When seeing over slave server replicated file system, it has the same creation date, same permissions but the owner is not Charlie, is other user which doesn't matter here.

```
root@slave:/home/charlie/replica# ls -ltr
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 robert   robert  0 May 26 08:56 test
```

When changing manually the owner to charle with root, it changes the replica_editor owner to another one.

```
root@slave:/home/charlie/replica# chown charlie:charlie test
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 charlie   charlie  0 May 26 08:56 test

charlie@master-client:~/replica_editor$ ls -ltr
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 johan   johan  0 May 26 08:56 test
```

Why is this happening while I'm not specifying anything about users over the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I could assimilate this:

The master-client server has some users, glusterfs-slave doesn't know which users are this, so it makes as owner of the remote files the same user from master-client but identified by his main UID. I think like a remote form. As this

```
root@master-client:/home/charlie/replica# ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 charlie   charlie  0 May 26 08:56 test
root@slave:/home/charlie/replica# ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1004   1004  0 May 26 08:56 test
```

When seeing master-client passwd file, I could see this:

```
root@master-client:~# cat /etc/passwd | grep 1004
charlie:x:1004:1004
```

looking the same in slave passwd file, I saw this:

```
root@slave:~# cat /etc/passwd |grep charlie
charlie:x:1002:1002
```

If I want the replica files to be owned by slave-charle user, I only have to edit carefully passwd file and change charlie UID to the same as master-client

```
root@slave:~# vim /etc/passwd
before:    charlie:x:1002:1002
after:     charlie:x:1004:1004
```

If UID 1004 is already a user's UID, just exchange them.
Then automatically we will see this:

```
root@slave:/home/charlie/replica# ls -ltr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 charlie   charlie  0 May 26 08:56 test
```